JSON Parsing from a log file
I'm working on a JSON parser which should be able to read valid JSONs from a file, the problem I'm facing is there might be more than on JSON in a file(one line containing multiple JSONs or one JSON in multiple lines), is there any way I could parse it?
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
        String line;
        StringBuilder jsonBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            jsonBuilder.append(line.trim());
            if (line.trim().endsWith("}")) {

                try (JsonParser jsonParser = Json.createParser(new StringReader(jsonBuilder.toString()))) {
                    Deque<String> context = new ArrayDeque<>();
                    StringBuilder currentObject = new StringBuilder();

                    while (jsonParser.hasNext()) {
                        Event event = jsonParser.next();

                        switch (event) {
                            case START_OBJECT:
                                context.push("object");
                                currentObject.append("{");
                                break;
                            case END_OBJECT:
                                context.pop();
                                currentObject.append("}");
                                if (context.isEmpty()) {
                                    System.out.println("Parsed JSON: " + currentObject.toString());
                                    currentObject = new StringBuilder();
                                }
                                else {
                                    currentObject.append(",");
                                }
                                break;
                            case START_ARRAY:
                                context.push("array");
                                currentObject.append("[");
                                break;
                            case END_ARRAY:
                                context.pop();
                                currentObject.append("]");
                                break;
                            case KEY_NAME:
                                currentObject.append("\"").append(jsonParser.getString()).append("\":");
                                break;
                            case VALUE_STRING:
                            case VALUE_NUMBER:
                                currentObject.append(jsonParser.getString());
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                jsonBuilder.setLength(0);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

It fetches me complete JSON spanning multiple lines, but couldn't handle the case of multiple JSON in a single line.
Using javax's JsonParser
I tried to have an stack which keeps track of the opening and ending of the JSON object, but couldn't track if multiple JSON are in the same line

'Multiple jsons'. So you are creating non-standard json parser.  I'd say your appoarch using line based reading is not helping you. Switch to characterd based parsing. And think of the separator between the 'JSON's. The result will be a List<JSONObject> ?

I'm planning on processing the JSONObject once I parse, but the result could be List as well!

Will there be only JSON in the file or other non JSON logs?

Only valid JSON logs would be present in the file
